# How can I prove $ f $ is a constant when $ \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h^3}\int_{-h}^{h}f(x+t)t\,dt=0 $?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $ f $ be a continuous function on $ (-\infty,\infty) $, such that for all $ x\in\mathbb{R} $, we have $ \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{h^3} \int_{-h}^h f(x+t)t\,dt=0 $. Please prove that $ f $ is a constant function. For this problem, here is my try. If I define $ F(t)=\int_0^t f(s) \, ds $, I have
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{h^3}\int_{-h}^h f(x+t)t\,dt=\frac{1}{h^2}(F(x+h)+F(x-h))-\frac{1}{h^3} \int_{x-h}^{x+h}F(t) \, dt.
\end{eqnarray}
But I cannot solve it as the two terms above may not have limits. Can you give me some hints and references?

Comment: Hint: you're not just proving $f$ is constant. You can actually prove something much more specific about $f$.

Comment: Can you give more information? I am confused about your statements.

Comment: Let's pretend we know that $f$ is constant. In that case, which constant could it be?

Comment: I think if we suppose that $ f $ is exactly $ 1 $, there is no problem. $ f $ needn't be $ 0 $.

Comment: Try explicitly calculating the limit when $f$ is 1.

Comment: As $ \int_{-h}^{h}tdt=0 $, the limit is $ 0 $. What's the problem?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I am being quite stupid today.

Comment: I changed $t dt$ (coded as `t dt`) to $t\,dt$ (coded as `t\,dt`) in several places in this question. Can you see how that is more legible and looks better? $\qquad$